# TypeORM array is not supported in postgres?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, typescript, typeorm

I have a column `kid_ages` which is `Integer[]`. When migrating, I get the following error:

`DataTypeNotSupportedError: Data type "Array" in "home.kid_ages" is not supported by "postgres" database.`

I tried adding the following options to my column:

```
type: 'array'
```

and:

```
array: true,
default: [],
nullable: false,
```

like this:

```
@Column({
  array: true,
  default: [],
  nullable: false,
})
kid_ages: string;
```

Answer (score 120, accepted):

The docs says, that it should work:

```
@Column("int", { array: true })
array: number[];
```

this is from the example https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/test/functional/database-schema/column-types/postgres/entity/Post.ts

In your code the array property is no array.
Have you tried `kid_ages: string[];`?

Comment: hmm, I seem to be getting an error using this: " You need to provide explicit type" Im using the following nullable type:

  @Field({ nullable: true })


  @Column('text', { array: true })


  tags?: string[] | null

Comment: I am no TypeORM Expert but you could try to default the null value to an empty array ``@Column({
    type: "text",
    array: true,
    default: []
})``

Answer (score 43):

For people looking to deal with arrays or string within your entities, based on @thopaw 's answer, you can use the following code:

```js
@Column("text", { array: true })
kid_ages: string[];
```

Answer (score 24):

As mentioned above, you can create Postgres' array column with next code:

```
@Column("int", { array: true })
kid_ages: number[];
```

If you then need to find some kid with age 5, use this:

```
kid = getRepository('kid')
        .createQueryBuilder()
        .where(':kid_age = ANY (kid.kid_ages)', { kid_age: 5 });
```

Comment: actually today (^0.3.0) it's just enough to use this one:
`repository.find({ 
where: {
 kid_ages: ArrayContains([5]),
}}`

Answer (score 14):

I tried all of the solutions already mentioned, but none of them worked. Finally found solution among the Github issues in TypeORM repo.

I quote the solution:

> This was a simple fix, the type of the column shouldn't be an array.
> Changed to this and it now works:
>
> ```
> @Column({array: true})
> tags: string;
> ```
>
> Better documentation on arrays would have been useful.

[Source](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/2760#issuecomment-417986803)

Answer (score 10):

My solution for Postgres for checking array inclusion is as follows:

I have defined the column as follows:

```
    @Column("text", { array: true, default: "{}" })
    tags: string[];
```

```
this.getFindQueryBuilder().where("recipe.tags && ARRAY[:...tags]", {tags: tags})
```

"getFindQueryBuilder": Is a function to get shared SelectQueryBuilder in order to save code.

The important part here is the where clause that I have shown in the example.

Answer (score 5):

The important thing to note here that even declaring integer array, the default should be defined as an empty object.

```
@Column("int", { array: true, default: {} })
ages: Number[];
```

Answer (score 3):

For array, you can use `simple-array` as the type

Comment: Yes, there is an example https://stackoverflow.com/a/64301112/1074834