# Is it possible for an array of number in postgresql using typeorm?

Tags: postgresql, typescript, typeorm

I have been trying to make an array of numbers in type orm in my User entity, but type orm keeps showing up this problem

The code

```
@Entity()
class User {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    username: string;

    @Column()
    password: string;

    @Column()
    points: number;

    @Column()
    time: number[];
};
```

And the error in terminal is it :

> (node:25398) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DataTypeNotSupportedError: Data type "Array" in "User.time" is not
> supported by "postgres" database.
> at new DataTypeNotSupportedError (/home/vinicius/www/Projects/Quizzer/backend/node_modules/typeorm/error/DataTypeNotSupportedError.js:7:28)
> at /home/vinicius/www/Projects/Quizzer/backend/node_modules/typeorm/metadata-builder/EntityMetadataValidator.js:74:27
> at Array.forEach ()
> at EntityMetadataValidator.validate (/home/vinicius/www/Projects/Quizzer/backend/node_modules/typeorm/metadata-builder/EntityMetadataValidator.js:71:36)
> at /home/vinicius/www/Projects/Quizzer/backend/node_modules/typeorm/metadata-builder/EntityMetadataValidator.js:42:74
> at Array.forEach ()
> at EntityMetadataValidator.validateMany (/home/vinicius/www/Projects/Quizzer/backend/node_modules/typeorm/metadata-builder/EntityMetadataValidator.js:42:25)
> at Connection.buildMetadatas (/home/vinicius/www/Projects/Quizzer/backend/node_modules/typeorm/connection/Connection.js:498:33)
> at Connection. (/home/vinicius/www/Projects/Quizzer/backend/node_modules/typeorm/connection/Connection.js:128:30)
> at step (/home/vinicius/www/Projects/Quizzer/backend/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:141:27)
> (node:25398) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async
> function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was
> not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled
> promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict`
> (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode).
> (rejection id: 1)
> (node:25398) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are
> not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit
> code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57611633/typeorm-array-is-not-supported-in-postgres):

```js
@Entity()
class User {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    username: string;

    @Column()
    password: string;

    @Column()
    points: number;

    @Column("int", { array: true })
    time: number[];
};
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also make it like this

```
@Column({ type: 'simple-array' })
time: number[]
```

Answer (score 0):

The array type is supported, but as per the documentation you have to explicitly mention that it is an array in such a way:

```
@Column("int", {array: True})
time: number[]
```

If you still get an error related to the default value, try using the following syntax.

```
@Column("int", {array: True, default: []})
```