# Store array of string in typeorm postgres database

Tags: sql, postgresql, typeorm

I would like to store an array of strings in my Postgres database, I have the below code but it is not working as I want:

```
  @Column({type: 'text', array: true, nullable: true })
  names: string[] = [];
```

I got the following error:

```
PostgreSQL said: malformed array literal: "["james"]"
Detail: "[" must introduce explicitly-specified array dimensions.
```

Anything I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I was able to resolve this with

```
  @Column('simple-array', { nullable: true, array: true })
  city: string[];
```

Comment: In my case TypeORM saved string as "{"a", "b", "c"}" and could not parse it properly when fetched from DB. What helped was adding `array: true` to column definition: `@Column({type: "simple-array", array: true})`

Answer (score 2):

This should work for an array.

```
@Column('text', { array: true })
names: string[];
```